# OpenCV3.1 background substraction

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

Can someone explain to me how the parameters "**history**", "**varThreshold**" and "**detectShadow**" work in **cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()** method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the background subtractor analyses the image and removes the "still" pixels.
According to [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#createbackgroundsubtractormog2), the `history` is likely the amount of time (in frames) you consider to understand which the still pixels are, the `varThreshold` is the threshold distance (squared Mahalanobis distance) you use to choose whether a pixel is still or not, and `detectShadow` tells the algorithm to detect the shadows in your scene and mark them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and helping me understand them.@magicleon

Comment: You're welcome, happy coding! (and huh, begging time, if I solved your problem mark the answer as solution, so I get reps, and people can see this question as solved ;) )